# AS3 ExternalInterface: Control a movie from another window

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

How can I control a flash movie in a window from a child (pop-up) window invoked via ExternalInterface's call method?

The name of the movie is `myMovie`. Using javascript in the popup, I try to access a function in the movie using  `document['myMovie'].flashFunction()`. However, since the javascript is in the popup window and the flash is in another, the browser complains that the function is undefined.

This would have worked if the javascript and the movie were in the same window.

I use Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pop up you can reference the original window with `window.opener` like this:

```
window.opener.document.myMovie.flashFunction();
```